# High number of interrupts on Ubuntu 15.04 on Dell XPS 13 2015 (9343)

Tags: dell, power-management, 15.04, powertop, interrupts

In powertop I noticed a high number of interrupts 'INT3432', which I *think* would be either the touchpad or sound card.
I am concerned on the effect on the power consumption and battery life.

FYI I applied all the recommmended powertop settings.

In powertop I see:

```
Summary: 7466.3 wakeups/second,  13.6 GPU ops/seconds, 0.0 VFS ops/sec and 63.9% CPU use

Power est.              Usage       Events/s    Category       Description
  17.8 W     72.3 ms/s     5747.5       Interrupt      [7] INT3432:00
  3.86 W    424.6 ms/s     1201.2       Process        /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
  3.12 W      4.8 pkts/s                Device         Network interface: wlan1 (wl)
```

In dmesg I see:

```
[    3.088251] input: DLL0665:01 06CB:76AD UNKNOWN as /devices/pci0000:00/INT3433:00/i2c-9/i2c-DLL0665:01/0018:06CB:76AD.0001/input/input13
```

And /proc/interrupts shows the very high number of interrupts for whatever-that-is:

```
          CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3
  0:         22          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC-edge      timer
  1:       1198        884       4906        644  IR-IO-APIC-edge      i8042
  6:          0          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC-fasteoi   dw_dmac
  7:     798517     364970    2524051     438847  IR-IO-APIC-fasteoi   INT3432:00, INT3433:00
  8:          0          0          0          1  IR-IO-APIC-edge      rtc0
  9:        579        205       1217        246  IR-IO-APIC-fasteoi   acpi
 12:        117         27        643         30  IR-IO-APIC-edge      i8042
 19:      64153         37        180         22  IR-IO-APIC  19-fasteoi   wlan1
 21:         10          4         42          5  IR-IO-APIC  21-fasteoi   ehci_hcd:usb3
 39:       9769       5817      48867       8822  IR-IO-APIC  39-fasteoi   DLL0665:01
 40:          0          0          0          0  DMAR_MSI-edge      dmar0
 41:          0          0          0          0  DMAR_MSI-edge      dmar1
 42:          0          0          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI-edge      PCIe PME
 43:          0          0          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI-edge      PCIe PME
 44:         26         20        114         18  IR-PCI-MSI-edge      xhci_hcd
 45:         16          2          8          4  IR-PCI-MSI-edge      rtsx_pci
 46:       9467      13498       8372      18819  IR-PCI-MSI-edge      0000:00:1f.2
 47:     114295      73782      53254      23185  IR-PCI-MSI-edge      i915
 48:        282          2          3         18  IR-PCI-MSI-edge      snd_hda_intel
 49:          2          1          1         11  IR-PCI-MSI-edge      mei_me
 50:       1066        159         29        130  IR-PCI-MSI-edge      snd_hda_intel
NMI:          1          1          1          1   Non-maskable interrupts
LOC:     140434     141971     144669     128459   Local timer interrupts
SPU:          0          0          0          0   Spurious interrupts
PMI:          1          1          1          1   Performance monitoring interrupts
IWI:        328        278        320        262   IRQ work interrupts
RTR:          2          0          0          0   APIC ICR read retries
RES:      26683      23782      35907      22000   Rescheduling interrupts
CAL:      13819      13262       9013      13611   Function call interrupts
TLB:      19832      19727      17178      16316   TLB shootdowns
TRM:          0          0          0          0   Thermal event interrupts
THR:          0          0          0          0   Threshold APIC interrupts
MCE:          0          0          0          0   Machine check exceptions
MCP:          9          9          9          9   Machine check polls
HYP:          0          0          0          0   Hypervisor callback interrupts
ERR:         12
MIS:          0
```

So my questions are:

1. how can I confirm what this interrupt is?
2. is it expected to have so many of them?
3. is there any way to improve on this, to improve the battery life?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be the trackpad. Don't use it and press 'r' in powertop, the number should be low. Move your finger around fast on the trackpad and press 'r' again, the number should be very high.

Comment: Could you please expand your answer and eventually add something to the question parts 2 and 3? Thank you!

Comment: @John Though I do think this should be considered an answer as-is, would you be willing to [edit] it to expand it with more information? As I believe ByteCommander is saying, this would benefit from an explanation of *why* it seems to be the trackpad and--if you know--whether or not this is normal. (If it's not normal, and you happen to know what may be causing it and how that could be addressed, that would be helpful information also.)

Comment: Indeed it does seem to be the trackpad, thanks John.  If you had a little bit of time to expand on your answer that would be an even bigger thank you, but no worries if not.